# Graphic UI with one listview below and one rotate image above

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, rotation, android-gallery

I would like to create the UI like the image below[image]

in the bottom: like a gallery or rotate image, i don't know exactly.

Thanks!

Comment: kindly have a look at [http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/04/18/scrolling-tabs-in-android/](http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/04/18/scrolling-tabs-in-android/)